Check if gateway address is within IP Subnet
I'm trying to determine if a gateway address in with the same subnet as another IP Address.
The code I'm using is :


var ip2long = function( ip ){
  var components;
    
  if ( components = ip.match(/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/) ) {
    var iplong = 0;
    var power  = 1;
    for ( var i=4; i>=1; i-=1 ) {
      iplong += power * parseInt( components[i] );
      power  *= 256;
    }
    return iplong;
  }
  else return -1;
}
    
var inSubNet = function( ip, subnet ) {   
  var mask, base_ip, long_ip = ip2long(ip);
  if ( ( mask = subnet.match(/^(.*?)\/(\d{1,2})$/) ) && ( ( base_ip=ip2long( mask[1] ) ) >= 0) ) {
    var freedom = Math.pow(2, 32 - parseInt(mask[2]));
    return (long_ip > base_ip) && (long_ip < base_ip + freedom - 1);
  }
  else return false;
}

ipaddress = '192.168.10.20'
gateway = '192.168.250.1'
mask = '16'

console.log(inSubNet( ipaddress, gateway + '/' +  mask ));



This returns false for the values used.  If I change the subnet so the third octet is 10 or lower then it works. If it's 11 or more then it returns false.
If I've understood the subnet correctly I would expect any gateway address 192.168.x.x to return true.
Can some one advise how I can do this.
Thanks

You can simply use AND with the subnetmask and compare the octets: e.g. IP1: 192.168.10.123, IP2: 192.168.10.122, Subnetmask: 255.255.255.254, fourth octet: (123 & 254) == (122 & 254)

Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain please.

The subnet mask has the format of an IP address, e.g. 255.255.255.0. You can use the bitwise AND operator to separate network part and host part. If two IP addresses have the same network part, they are in the same subnet. The tables in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet can help.

Let's stop using var.

You can first convert the bitmask into a subnetmask. Then, you can use bitwise AND with the subnetmask and compare the octets.


const ipaddress = '192.168.10.20'
const gateway = '192.168.250.1'
const mask = '16'

console.log(inSubNet(ipaddress, gateway + '/' + mask));

function inSubNet(ipaddress, gateway, bitmask) {
  function bitmaskToSubnetmaskOctets(bitmask) {
    if (!/^\d{1,2}$/.test(bitmask) || +bitmask > 32)
      throw Error('Bitmask has invalid format');
    bitmask = +bitmask;
    const octets = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      const bits = Math.min(Math.max(0, (bitmask - (i * 8))), 8);
      octets[i] = parseInt('1'.repeat(bits) + '0'.repeat(8 - bits), 2);
    }
    return octets;
  }

  function ipAddressToOctets(ipaddress) {
    if (!/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/.test(ipaddress) || ipaddress.split('.').some(octet => +octet > 255))
      throw Error('IP address has invalid format');
    return ipaddress.split('.').map(i => +i);
  }

  function gatewayToOctetsAndSubnetmaskOctets(gateway) {
    if (!/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{1,2}$/.test(gateway))
      throw Error('Gateway address has invalid format');
    const [ipaddress, bitmask] = gateway.split('/');
    return [ipAddressToOctets(ipaddress), bitmaskToSubnetmaskOctets(bitmask)];
  }

  const ipaddressOctets = ipAddressToOctets(ipaddress);
  const [gatewayOctets, subnetmaskOctets] = gatewayToOctetsAndSubnetmaskOctets(gateway);

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if ((ipaddressOctets[i] & subnetmaskOctets[i]) !== (gatewayOctets[i] & subnetmaskOctets[i]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}



